# Android Email, CSS Media Queries, & Outlook Exchange

Tags: android, css, email, exchange-server, media-queries

I am using the following embedded  tag and media query **inside HTML email**:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-device-width:800px) {
    /* styles */
}
</style>
```

I have a problem with this on the Android native mail client (Froyo; testing on a Galaxy S, and a Galaxy S2):

- When I send email to a Gmail account and check it on the email client, the media query works great.
- When I send email to our company email addresses - which are run on a Microsoft Exchange Server (I believe Exchange 2010), the media query does not run at all.

I don't know how to view the source of the email on the phone, but it seems like the email's HTML is being modified by Exchange before it reaches the device.  I would expect it to modify the HTML when viewing in Outlook or via Outlook Web Access, but I'm not sure why the version on the device device is getting modified, and if so, in what way it is modified.

Any suggestions?
Anyone run into anything similar, or at least know how to "view source" of an email as it is stored on the device?  (Once forwarded, it would be modified by the receiving email platform, right?)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is probably a policy enforced by the server that all media is stripped out before being stored in a user's mailbox.  This would be not unlike blocking certain attachment extensions, etc.  Gmail doesn't have that problem because it doesn't have the same policies in place.  The issue isn't the client so much as it is the Exchange server.

Comment: You raise a good point.  I will test and see if any embedded styles are running on the phone when viewing Exchange-delivered email, perhaps just not the ones inside the media query.  I'll report back.

Comment: What is odd is that the iPhone will render the email using the media queries, so Exchange is not *always* stripping the embedded <style> tag. I just tested the embedded style tag, and nothing -- even when outside a media query -- ran on the Android mail client for Exchange mail.  iPhone is fine.  Android Email client with Gmail is also fine.  Outlook Web Access and Outlook Desktop render the styles, but media queries fail.  Argh!